# for multiple access points on one SSID, should I broadcast SSID information from all of them?

Tags: access-point, 802.1

Should I be broadcasting my SSID from multiple access points that are sharing the SSID and network segment, or should I only broadcast from one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no disadvantage to broadcasting it from more than one AP. Broadcasting from all of them will certainly make it easier for your users to connect.

I'm currently broadcasting the same SSID from over 400 APs and all is well.

Do you have a specific concern about doing this?

Comment: +1 This is completely normal for public and semi-public WAPs. In corporate environments it's increasingly common to disable SSID broadcast and use some sort of policy configuration.

Comment: I want the SSID to be broadcasted (i.e. the user needs to be able to detect the network from their OS), but I was concerned that maybe broadcasting from multiple APs would cause conflict or extra chatter. I am having a lot of issues when running two APs with packets dropping every 30 seconds or so, and I wonder if it is due to my wireless card switching between the APs. I have the two APs for the network on channels 1 and 11.